# WLST Scripting Error - Must Activate Changes Bug

Tags: weblogic, wlst

I wrote a script to automate *Weblogic* deployments and during the `undeploy` and sometimes the `deploy` part of the script there is an error message that says, **"The task cannot be processed further until the current edit session is activated. When this occurs, task processing will continue. The user can exit the deployer tool without affecting the task."** When this happens I have to click the "*Activate Changes*" on the GUI of the admin console for the script to continue and do what I want it to do. **Are there any WLST Jython programmers out there that know how to avoid this issue?** I am trying to run the script without touching the GUI.

Also, sometimes the *State* of the managed server changes to 'deploy initializing'. When this happens I know that things are really messed up. I think this happens when I choose the other option "Undo All Changes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good answer of code for this in this [**blog**](http://wlstbyexamples.blogspot.com.au/2010/09/deployment-script-using-wlst.html#.WONUfkZ95hE)

Answer (score 1):

Its best to always do small bits, activate those changes and then proceed to the next task.

When doing an undeploy and deploy, its always better to undeploy, activate the change and then do a deploy and activate again, this way things remain clean else you may have conflicts when activating all changes in 1 go.

and no you dont have to activate from console, you can do from wlst using activate([timeout], [block])

Comment: @SridharS, can you provide an example code here ..?

Comment: @SridharS, can you provide an example code here ..?  I have the deploy(application, path, targets=servername) command  executed from my python program..  which hangs up  with the following log `[Deployer:149140]The task cannot be processed further until the current edit session is activated. When this occurs, task processing will continue. The user can exit the deployer tool without affecting the task..............................................................`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure to commit one transaction per session. This way you would not miss your earlier undeploy/deploy status due to the issue incurred by current deploy/undeploy task. Please find sample code block below.

```
    app-list = [app1 app2 app3 ... app60]
    for app in app-list:
        edit()
        startEdit()
        app-path = "<path-to-your-apps>/" + app
        deploy(app, app-path, targets=<your-targets>)
        print 'deployed ' + app
        activate()
```

Comment: @praveen-raj-kumar, can you provide an example code here ..?  I have the deploy(application, path, targets=servername) command  executed from my python program..  which hangs up  with the following log `[Deployer:149140]The task cannot be processed further until the current edit session is activated. When this occurs, task processing will continue. The user can exit the deployer tool without affecting the task..............................................................`

Comment: Added it to my original answer